# Iterating over row and editing strings in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string

Good morning,

I have exhaustively searched for how best to do two things in Python/Pandas, and have not yet found the answer.

I have a df such as:

| User | Role |
| --- | --- |
| Roger Dodger (rogerdodger) | user |
| Edwin Cullen (edwincullen) | user |
| Hunter Andrews (hunterandrews) | user |

I would like iterate over the user column and leave only the text inside the parenthesis, with a result such as:

| User | Role |
| --- | --- |
| rogerdodger | user |
| edwincullen | user |
| hunterandrews | user |

I've found many successful ways for iterating.  I've not found a way to do the string edits cleanly.  I've seen some regex suggestions but am not all that familiar with how to implement them based on the other examples given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to do that.

One way would be using [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) and a custom lambda function as follows

```
df['User'] = df['User'].apply(lambda x: x[x.find('(')+1:x.find(')')])

[Out]:

            User  Role
0    rogerdodger  user
1    edwincullen  user
2  hunterandrews  user
```

Another way could be with [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) as follows

```
df['User'] = df['User'].str.extract(r'\((.*?)\)', expand=False)

[Out]:

            User  Role
0    rogerdodger  user
1    edwincullen  user
2  hunterandrews  user
```

---

**Notes**:

- If needed, one can also store the username in a different column, such as the column `username` as follows

  ```
  df['username'] = df['User'].str.extract(r'\((.*?)\)', expand=False)

  [Out]:
                               User  Role       username
  0      Roger Dodger (rogerdodger)  user    rogerdodger
  1      Edwin Cullen (edwincullen)  user    edwincullen
  2  Hunter Andrews (hunterandrews)  user  hunterandrews
  ```